# What do you think about DTOs in Spring Data JPA project?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

First of all, I am not a junior programmer. I'm just looking for best-practice.

How do you use entities and DTOs into your Spring Data JPA projects? 
Assume there is our layers:

1. Repositories (as interface extended from `JpaRepository`)
2. Services (as Spring `@Service`-annotated beans)
3. Other code

And I have no problem in my code inside service-layer - read Entity from Repository, modify it and store into database back. But I have a discomfort of using database stored data outside from service layer. There are two approaches to do this:

1. to convert all entities into DTO when them leave service layer (inside particular Service class directly)
2. not to convert them right inside service classes but to be sure you don't access to linked entities to prevent `session is lost` exceptions. This case you have to read all linked entities obviously inside service `@Transctional`-annotated method.

First approach seems more overloaded. When you have to access service class from the other service class you might not need entity-to-DTO and DTO-to-entity transformations. But this leads you to duplicate almost all methods in service class to return entity and DTO both - one is for using outside of service layer and the other one is for using inside of service layer but from the other class.

Sure I know another approach. It is to use all you need repositories from every service class. But it seems to be against GRASP principles. Correct me if I was incorrect.

And another problem is to use automated Entity-to-DTO mappers like ModelMapper. When your DTO contains linked DTO (like joined entities) ModelMapper may go into recursion that leads `stack overflow` exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

Both your approaches raise some concerns. The main concern about the first approach is that you'll end up with a lot of duplicate methods. This isn't exactly a problem though, because both methods have a clear goal:

1. One of the methods will actually implement the business logic you want to execute, and will return an entity.
2. The other method will call the first one, and only do the mapping from an entity to a DTO.

Now, you could also extract all those methods that return a DTO to a separate class (**Single Responsibility Principle**). How you would call that class? Well, if you extract all those methods, you successfully implemented the **Facade Pattern**. This means that if you have an `OrderService`, you now also have an `OrderFacade`.

Now that we have two classes in stead of one, we may end up with other issues, such as where to put the `@Transactional`? The answer to that is; within the facade. A facade is allowed to call multiple service methods, and by adding it to the facade, both happen within the same transaction.

Additionally, you may wonder, when do I call `OrderService`, when do I call `OrderFacade`? Ideally, if you use domain driven design, the only class that is allowed to expose anything to other domains, is the facade.

This means that:

1. **Services within the same domain are allowed to call each other**. For example, you're allowed to call `OrderLineService` within `OrderService` (given that they both belong to the "order" domain).
2. **A controller** exposes things, and **should only** be allowed to **call a facade**. This means that `OrderController` should autowire `OrderFacade` (and not `OrderService`).
3. Services within other domains are not allowed to call each other. This means that you can't call `CustomerService` within `OrderService` or the other way around.

While the first two are pretty easy to implement, what do you do when you really need some information from another domain within your business logic? For example, you may want to know if a customer actually exists before they can place an order. In that case, you can implement the **Adapter Pattern**.

For example, you can create a `CustomerOrderAdapter` interface within your "order" domain, containing a `boolean isAllowedToCreateOrder(String customerName)`.

Within the "customer" domain, you can now implement the `CustomerOrderAdapter`. Be aware, **an adapter shouldn't return entities either**.

This also means that **entities from other domains shouldn't be mapped** with JPA/Hibernate. Communication between domains should only happen through adapters. You may think that this leads to multiple queries, and you're right. Wouldn't that be bad performance? No idea, probably not, but as always with performance: you should measure it.

So, wrapped up you end up with:

[image: Class diagram]

Now you may think, that this looks like overkill. However, the benefits of using this architecture are:

1. You get **an overview of what's being exposed** very quickly, just by checking the facades (rather than looking around within your services to see what returns a DTO and what doesn't).
2. It's **modular**. As you can see, the only dependency between the domains are the adapters. This also allows you to more easily refactor to microservices.